# What is the difference between message_generation and genmsg?

Tags: ros, genmsg, tutorial, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was following the tutorials and I have a question about the message generation. Once you generate a service with messages you need to modify the package.xml file:

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

That part is cover, I have no problems there. Now, after that, you need to modify the CMakeLists file, you need to add:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED_COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)
...
add_dependencies(<node_name> package_name_generate_messages_cpp)
```

But then, following the tutorials those two lines have different names for the message generation:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED_COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)
...
add_dependencies(<node_name> package_name_gencpp)
```

What is the difference between message_generation and genmsg?

In the add_dependencies function, the second function declared is for the messages, but why one is package_name_gencpp and the other package_name_generate_messages_cpp??? I am confused here. So, the name for the message generation dependency can be whatever I want. But where is that defined, how does ROS know the second dependency is for messages???

[Tutorial Publisher Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

[Tutorial Service Client](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29)

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150806/what-is-the-difference-between-message_generation-and-genmsg?/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The later tutorials (from https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials) are not up-to-date. (You might fill a ticket for this in the GitHub repository for the maintainer to update the tutorials.) You should only use `message_generation` and the targets ending in `_generate_messages_cpp`.

For the target it does not make a difference since they are both identifical. The new one is much more intuitively names then the old abbreviated one (`_gencpp`).

But for the dependency in your package.xml file it does. `genmsg` only provides the CMake generator functions, `message_generation` will actually depend on all default supported generators and makes sure that they are actually present. Otherwise e.g. when building Debians on the farm for a package containing messages it might not have any language specific message generators installed.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3